# How much do US banks rely on deposits from retail customers to operate? (checking, savings, CD's, etc)

Tags: united-states, banking

How much do US banks rely on deposits from retail customers to operate? Deposits such as checking accounts, savings accounts, certificates of deposit, etc. Let's say overtime this number trends to zero. Would banks have to shut down ? How would this fundamentally impact their business ?

Comment: what kind of bank? The answer will differ from a community bank, to a regional bank, to a bank that deals mostly with businesses. Let alone a Credit Union.

Comment: I think it is fair to say that no banks make money directly from deposits.  Banks pay customers (via interest) on deposits so they can make money using the deposits for loans and other things.  So no banks make money on them directly but all banks need them to have capital to make money in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question revolves around what the bank's focus is - individual private citizens (consumer banking) or corporate clients.  While every bank targets both groups, some specialize.

That being said, as a general proposition, I think banks couldn't survive without deposit accounts, since they are what form the bank's capital base to facilitate lending activity, without which the only remaining revenue would be account fees and consulting/private banking services (such as wealth management, etc.).